# how to get the timezone of a bigcommerce store

Tags: php, datetime, bigcommerce

I am getting a problem while i am trying to access the timezone of a bigcommerce store
using the getTime() function of bigcommerce api:

```
$time=Bigcommerce::getTime();
print_r($time);
```

it always returning me following output:

```
Array ( [date] => 2013-08-17 12:15:55 [timezone_type] => 1 [timezone] => +00:00 )
```

but i have set following timezone at my bigcommerce store:

```
 Mountain Time (US & Canada) (GMT -7:00)
```

Can somebody please tell me if there is any way to get the right timezone of the store.....

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://amberpos.zendesk.com/entries/22345847-Setting-Your-Time-Zone-in-BigCommerce

Comment: I looked in their API, but I don't see any method that returns the time zone setting.  If you already know it, you can convert it using PHP's time zone support.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to currently retrieve the store's default timezone setting via the API. Ideally, it should be part of the store endpoint...What are you trying to do?

The time resource by itself returns the epochseconds. It is mostly intended as a health check for the store.

```
{
    "time": 1378757860
}
```